# DigitalOcean - How to route website.net traffic to website.com except for one page?

Tags: nginx, redirect, digital-ocean, nginx-location, nginx-config

In DigitalOcean, we have all `website.net` pointing all traffic to `website.com`. Anyone accessing the `.net` will be redirected to `.com`

We have a scenario where we want the above to remain intact, but we want *just* **one** page to be loaded on the `.net` and not be redirected to the `.com`

`website.net/reset` should be accessible without any redirect happening to `.com` but we're not really sure how to do that, as it's an edge case we're solving where this is the only solution at the moment.

Any idea how to make `website.net/reset` not redirect to `website.com` using DigitalOcean?

**UPDATE:**

**DNS for `.com`**
[image]

**DNS for `.net`**
[image]

**Nginx configuration for `.net`**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.website.net;

    # Match /reset request exactly and redirect   
    location /reset {
      # Redirect /reset to google does not work, redirects to website.com instead
      # return 301 http://google.com/;
      # Redirect /reset to website.net/reset does not work, redirects to website.com instead
      return 301 http://www.website.net/reset;
    }

    # Redirect .net to .com
    return 301 https://www.website.com$request_uri;

    ...
}
```

Added DNS for `.com`/`.net` and nginx configuration for `.net`, but still `website.net/reset` redirects to `website.com`. Any idea how to change this so it goes to `website.net/reset` and not redirect to `website.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that would probably be to update the server configuration for the .net server to issue a 301 redirect response to the .com address for everything except website.com/reset. The details of this would depend on which web server you are using, eg nginx, apache, etc.

For Apache this could be done using the RedirectMatch directive:

```
<VirtualHost digitaloceanwebsite.net:80>
        ServerName digitaloceanwebsite.net
        # Respond with a 301 redirect to all requests not made to /reset, /other, or /different/page
        RedirectMatch permanent ^(?!\/reset$|\/other$|\/different\/page$) http://digitaloceanwebsite.com
        DocumentRoot "/srv/http/digitaloceanwebsite/net"
        <Directory "/srv/http/digitaloceanwebsite/net"> 
                ...
        </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost digitaloceanwebsite.com:80>
        ServerName digitaloceanwebsite.com
        DocumentRoot "/srv/http/digitaloceanwebsite/com"
        <Directory "/srv/http/digitaloceanwebsite/com"> 
                ...
        </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

If your websites are hosted on separate servers, just make sure that the website.net server has the RedirectMatch in its config.

Update response:

Looking at the nginx config that you posted, it looks like the 301 return in the server block is taking precedence over the location block.

This nginx config should work for what you want to do.

```
server {
    ...
    server_name www.website.net;

    # = specifies that this is an exact match which immediately takes precedence
    location = /reset {
        # location block for www.website.net/reset
    }

    # redirects all other requests
    location / {
        return 301 https://www.website.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Also, if you need to add other exceptions or just want to do some further reading on this, [this page at Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) has a good explanation of how nginx selects which location and server block to use.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added an update with the DNS records/nginx config but still can't get it to work. Any idea what needs to change for it to work?

Comment: @Wonka I updated my answer to provide a nginx config that should work. It looks like the website.com redirect in your config was taking precedence over the website.net/redirect location.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, works really well!